# milli seconds is missing in mongoDB date using DBCollection find(DBObject) method in Java

Tags: mongodb, date

I am trying to get a date from mongoDB 4.4 with java mongoDB driver 4.1 using `DBCollection find(DBObject)` method. The date is coming in `1993-06-16T00:00:00Z` format, we are expecting `1993-06-16T00:00:00.000Z` format.

In new mongoDB date format milli seconds is missing. Is this functionality of mongoDB 4.4? what do I should do to get the date with milli seconds?

Comment: I think if the milliseconds is not secified when creating a document, it will not be stored in the document. For example, `2020-10-14T00:00:00.001Z` is stored and can be retrieved as it is.

Comment: thanks for your response, I am reading the date (2020-10-14T00:00:00.001Z) from MongoDB using java mongo driver 4.1 which will support MongoDB 4.4. After fetching the date (2020-10-14T00:00:00.001Z) from MongoDB 4.4, the date is converting into 2020-10-14T00:00:01Z.. here milliseconds are missing. I don't understand what type of changes happened in mongo driver 4.1.